# Based on some condition need to use different Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

We are passing some parameters in our SQL query.
If any of these parameters is not null then we are setting one value.
Based on that value i have to use different join to join two tables.
please find below the code:

```
WITH check_fliter
     AS (SELECT CASE
                   WHEN    &protocol_Id IS NOT NULL
                        OR &order_status IS NOT NULL
                        OR &order_Id IS NOT NULL
                        OR &start_date IS NOT NULL
                        OR &end_date IS NOT NULL
                        OR &source_system IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                      'Y'
                   ELSE
                      'N'
                END
                   CSDS_ONLY
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT co.order_id,
       im.object_key_n,
       last_date_modified,
       source_org_system_id
  FROM csds_prod_owner.inbound_message im
 (CASE WHEN CSDS_ONLY = 'Y'
       THEN
            JOIN ctds_order co
            ON im.object_key_n = co.order_id
 ELSE
      LEFT OUTER JOIN  ctds_order co
           ON (im.object_key_n = decode(co.non_csds_order,'Y',DECODE( TRANSLATE(co.source_order_id,'0123456789',' '), NULL, co.source_order_id,-1),co.order_id))
 END)
```

When i am trying to execute this query  iam getting below error message.
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `LEFT JOIN` for both and then do the transformation back to an `INNER JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM csds_prod_owner.inbound_message im LEFT JOIN
     ctds_order co
     ON (CSDS_ONLY = 'Y' and im.object_key_n = co.order_id) or
        (CSDS_ONLY <> 'Y' and (im.object_key_n = decode(co.non_csds_order, 'Y', DECODE( TRANSLATE(co.source_order_id,'0123456789',' '), NULL, co.source_order_id,-1),co.order_id))
WHERE CSDS_ONLY <> 'Y' OR co.order_id is not null
```

I should add that that I don't really approve of `decode()`, when the `case` statement is much easier to follow.  However, I am not modifying that aspect of your code.